# 'yo angular' throwing errors

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I am following this tutorial to create a MEAN stack application: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhPFgqHz68o.

I am having Windows 8.1 and I have setup and coded the backend with Node.js which has no problem.

When I started with the frontend, all I tried to do was:

```
mkdir client
cd client
npm install -g yo
npm install -g generator-angular
yo angular
```

I answered all of the questions asked and then it began its process. Somewhere in between it said that there is a conflict and asked if it should overwrite `package.json`. I agreed to it by hitting `Enter` key since I did not see any other option.

I could see a lot of errors in the process.

Here is the `npm-debug.log`: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rahul-desai3/9f1d1d0a1ddeec2a4ad0/raw/npm-debug.log

I did it again with the command prompt with admin rights and it still ended up same as earlier.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** I am using `node v0.12.2` and `npm v2.7.4`.

**EDIT 2:** The log in the command prompt is so huge that I cant reach to the top where I actually issued that command. Here are the errors that I could get:

```
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\nod
e_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\gifsicle\node_mod
ules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\lnfs\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\grunt-cont
rib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\g
ifsicle\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\lnfs\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\nod
e_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\gifsicle\node_mod
ules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\globby\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\grunt-cont
rib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\g
ifsicle\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\globby\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\nod
e_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\gifsicle\node_mod
ules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\os-filter-obj\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\grunt-cont
rib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\g
ifsicle\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\os-filter-obj\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\optimis
t\0.6.1\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\is-utf8
\0.2.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\first-c
hunk-stream\1.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\exec-se
ries\1.0.1\package.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-svgo@4.1.2
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\archive
-type\2.1.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\figures
\1.3.5\package.tgz
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\nod
e_modules\imagemin\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\g
lob2base\README.md
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\grunt-cont
rib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-strea
m\node_modules\glob2base\README.md'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lnfs\1.
0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\is-path
-global\1.0.1\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\bin-che
ck\1.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lnfs\1.
0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\bin-che
ck\1.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\is-path
-global\1.0.1\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lazy-re
q\1.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\bin-ver
sion-check\2.1.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\tempfil
e\1.1.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\tempfil
e\1.1.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\url-reg
ex\2.1.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\tempfil
e\1.1.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\clean-c
ss\3.1.9\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\tempfil
e\1.1.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\glob\4.
5.3\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\squeak\
1.2.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\squeak\
1.2.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\unique-
stream\1.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\squeak\
1.2.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\globby\
1.2.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\globby\
1.2.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\downloa
d\4.1.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\decompr
ess\2.3.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\decompr
ess\2.3.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\decompr
ess\2.3.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\decompr
ess\2.3.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\bin-che
ck\1.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ordered
-read-streams\0.1.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\js-yaml
\2.0.5\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\downloa
d\3.3.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\downloa
d\3.3.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\downloa
d\3.3.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\downloa
d\3.3.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\downloa
d\3.3.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\downloa
d\3.3.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\source-
map\0.3.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\undersc
ore.string\2.2.1\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readabl
e-stream\1.0.33\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\async\0
.1.15\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ng-anno
tate\0.15.4\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\
2.4.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\
2.4.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\
2.4.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readabl
e-stream\1.1.13\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\
2.4.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\glob\4.
5.3\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\uglify-
js\2.4.20\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\minimat
ch\0.2.14\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\browser
ify-zlib\0.1.4\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\glob\3.
2.11\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\browser
ify-zlib\0.1.4\package.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-pngquant@4.1.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-jpegtran@4.1.0
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readabl
e-stream\1.1.13\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readabl
e-stream\1.1.13\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\
0.9.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\log-sym
bols\1.0.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\chalk\1
.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\pretty-
bytes\1.0.4\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\each-as
ync\1.1.1\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\coffee-
script\1.3.3\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\brace-e
xpansion\1.1.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\jshint\
2.7.0\package.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-optipng@4.2.0
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\iconv-l
ite\0.2.11\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\svgo\0.
5.1\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\
2.4.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\
2.4.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\
2.4.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\
1.0.2\package.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.5
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\cdnjs-c
dn-data\0.1.1\package.tgz
/


> phantomjs@1.9.16 install C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\karma-phantom
js-launcher\node_modules\phantomjs
> node install.js

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\node_m
odules\lodash\lodash.js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048

npm ERR! Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\grunt-con
trib-watch\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\grunt
-contrib-watch\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\projects\\meanapp\\client\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib-wat
ch\\node_modules\\lodash\\lodash.js' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
Download already available at C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phanto
mjs-1.9.8-windows.zip
Extracting zip contents
\
 Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\projects\meanapp\client\npm-debug.log
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
Removing C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\karma-phantomjs-launcher\node_m
odules\phantomjs\lib\phantom
Copying extracted folder C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1
.9.8-windows.zip-extract-1430549417367\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows -> C:\projects\me
anapp\client\node_modules\karma-phantomjs-launcher\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\ph
antom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\karm
a-phantomjs-launcher\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs.exe
-
> ws@0.4.32 install C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\karma\node_modules\s
ocket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\projects\meanapp\client\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_module
s\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\
Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-
gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\projects\meanapp\client\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed the ruby gems `sass` and `compass` that are required by yeoman. That solved the problem.